# Processing:How can I make a 9 become a 10?

Tags: processing

I'm a big guitar player, and I'm trying to learn every song from my favorite band, Rise Against. The problem is, some songs are tabbed in standard tuning and some in Eb. I don't want to constantly have to go back and forth, so I wanted to make a program to convert all standard songs to Eb tuning.

This is done by simply adding one to each fret. So if I'm supposed to bar chord the 1st fret in standard, I'll do it on the 2nd.

Here is a tab for "Give it All"

```
e|---------------|
H|---------------|
G|---------------|
D|-7---3---6---4-|
A|-4---4---4---4-|
E|---------------|

 Verse Part 1 (x2)
e|--------------------------------------|
H|--------------------------------------|
G|--------------7777----------7777-9999-|
D|-44--44--44---7777-44--44---7777-9999-|
A|-44--44--44---5555-44--44---5555-7777-|
E|-22--22--22--------22--22-------------|

Verse Part 2 (x2)
E|--------------------------------------|
H|--------------------------------------|
G|--------------7777----------7777-9999-|
D|-44--44--44---7777-44--44---7777-9999-|
A|-4422442244---5555-44--44---5555-7777-|
E|-2200220022--------22002200-----------|  

Chorus (2x)
E|--------------------------------------------|
H|--------------------------------------------|
G|--------------------------------------------|
D|----------99999999-111111111111111-77777777-|
A|-77777777-77777777-111111111111111-55555555-|
E|-55555555----------9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9----------|
```

That's part of it at least. My programming teacher helped me make this in Processing:

```
  void setup() {
      String lines[] = loadStrings("fretEx1.txt");
      println("there are " + lines.length + " lines");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.length; i++) {

      println(shiftLine(lines[i]));
  }
  System.out.println(Character.isDigit('9'));
}


//Takes a line of tablature (spelling?) and increases all fret number values by 1.
StringBuilder shiftLine(String tab) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(tab);
  for(int i=0; i<sb.length(); i++) {
    char ch = sb.charAt(i);
    if(Character.isDigit(ch) ) {
       ch++;
       sb.setCharAt(i,ch);
    }

  }
  return sb;
}
```

It works well until it converts a 9 to what should be a 10. Instead it puts a colon. How do you recommend fixing this? Also, I know there are plenty of other problems, but I'm focusing on this one right now. Thanks!

Comment: When this problem will be solved, and it will be soon, you will have another problem: how to manage the fact that two digits represent a single note, and how to display it without messing with the 5 other strings >= to this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that 10 isn't a digit. Take a look at [the ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/). The character on the ascii table succeeding 9 is the colon character. When you increment the ascii value for '9', you end up with ':'. You need to convert the ascii character to an integer, and then increment, before printing its value. You might also want to consider making room for numbers that incorporate two digits so that your tabs aren't out of whack.

Note that the ascii value for the digit '0' is 48. Hence, a simple algorithm (in Java/Processing) for converting an ascii digit character to its integer value:

```
if (Character.isDigit(someChar)) {
    int value = (int) someChar - 48;
}
```